# How to run a Bash script from terminal by calling input file and defining output file?

Tags: linux, bash

I have a bash script that I want to run directly from the terminal by defining the input and output files. How can I do that!

Here, the myscript.sh contains the files `test.tsv` as an input and `Out.tsv` as an output.

```
#! /bin/bash
    
awk 'BEGIN
    { 
    do some job
    }' test.tsv |
    
awk 'BEGIN
    { 
    do some job
    }' |
    
awk 'BEGIN
    { 
    do some job
    }' |
    
awk 'BEGIN
    { 
    do some job
    }' > Out.tsv
```

Where I want to run `myscript.sh` directly from the terminal command line by calling the input file and defining the output file.

```
bash myscript.sh -i test.tsv -o Out.tsv
```

Any suggestions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just `./myscript < test.csv > Out.csv` ?

Comment: Alright, then please let me know how to do that!